# ActiveRecord query for model not referenced in another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have something similar to the following 2 models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :student
end
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

I know I can find all people who are students with:

```
Person.joins(:student)
```

How can I find all the people who ***aren't*** students? Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord and not having to write a SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this statement:

```
Person.includes(:student).
       where(:students => {:id => nil})
```

or

```
Person.joins("LEFT JOIN students ON students.person_id = people.id").
       where(:students => {:id => nil})
```

I prefer the latter, because it doesn't select unneeded columns.

Comment: You're right. I like the 2nd statement. I don't know what the performance hit on a subquery is in PostgreSQL (the database we use in production). I was hoping that would be optimized to be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use rails 4 you can do it like this:

```
Person.where.not(:id => Student.select(:person_id))
```

Comment: The query it produces looks good, but doesn't return any rows (when it should): `SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE ("people"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "students"."person_id" FROM "students"))`. I have plenty of `Person` objects in the database whose `id`s are not in the `person_id` column of any `students` record. Interestingly, if I take out the `not` from the query, I do get the correct people who are students. I just don't get the converse when the `not` is there.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working for me is I had `nil` `person_id` fields in `Student`. So this is the query that ends up working for me: `Person.where.not(id: Student.select(:person_id).where.not(person_id: nil))`

Comment: Beware: This are two queries! And `Student.select(:person_id)` fetches much data from the database, if the Student table is large. See my answer for a better solution.

Comment: @GeorgLedermann it wasn't 2 queries from Rails' perspective, there was only 1 SQL query sent to the database. If you mean that it creates a subquery within a query, that's correct. Though I would hope a database would be smart about the execution.

Comment: @at. You are right, with Rails 4 it's one SQL statement including a subquery. In most cases, a join is faster than a subquery. The PostgreSQL optimizer can rewrite the query, so maybe it doesn't matter. To make sure, you should use `explain` to get the query plan.